# spring boot initializer was not available in intelij 2021.3.2 community

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am working on Spring boot Project using IntelliJ 2021.3.2 but I have not found Spring initializer in the project type's list

Comment: Please refer this link. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point out that the Spring Initializer is **only** available in the ultimate edition, not in the community edition. **If you are using the community version, there is no way to enable the Spring plugin here.**

In your case, probably the best case is using [Spring Initializer](https://start.spring.io/) from the web.

Comment: @elliot Can you please approve my answer?